# What is the cost of upgrading a contract (openzepplin upgradable contracts) in the mainnet?

Tags: hardhat, openzeppelin, upgrading, contract-upgrading

I'm a bit new to web3, right now trying to upgrade an upgradable contract using hardhat, but the funds on my wallet are never enough.
According to what I have researched, as of today (June 5, 2023). This is the formula I am using:

```
const gweiPrice = 0.000000062;
const ethValue = 1809.51;
const gasUsed = 3188286;
const total = gweiPrice * ethValue * gasUsed;
```

**Giving me a total of ~$357.70**. I have a wallet with ~$384 USD worth of ETH (maybe there is a fee I am missing?).

How do I get the gasUsed? This is the part were I am uncertain. I am first doing the upgrade on a local node using Ganache with a fork of the mainnet, upgrading the same contract and getting the gas value from the logs:
[image]

Am I using the right data? What other mechanisms can you suggest to me?